# Adding an Event Listener

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors, dom-events

How do we add an event listener on each item of the code only once, it's easy to do state management in the react but how do we do this in plain old javascript

```
     <div class="grid-container" id="ad">
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>   
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      <div class="grid-item" ></div>
      </div>
```

```
   let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item")

        for(let i=0;i<divs.length;i++) { 

            divs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            divs[i].style["background-color"] = "red";

        });
    }
```

Comment: There is no text or nothing inside the ```grid-item```, then where exactly you will handle the click??

Comment: remove `eventListener` on the clicked div.grid-item or from all div.grid-item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the options object in the event listener to make the event happen just once like this:

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
const changeBackgroundColor = e => {
 e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
divs.forEach(div => {
 div.addEventListener("click", changeBackgroundColor, {once: true});
})
```

Comment: How can I return the divs i'th value where I had clicked?

Comment: you can use e.target.value or e.currentTarget.value

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a named function rather than an anonymous one. And then use that named function to remove all listeners, in the same way you added them.

Here's a jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/v1akgpL6/

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");

/* Remove all event listeners */
const removeListeners = () => {
    for (let j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) { 
    divs[j].removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  }
}

/* Click event listener */
const clickHandler = (e) => {
  e.currentTarget.style["background-color"] = "red";
  removeListeners();
}

/* Add event listeners */
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}
```